# How to convert MotorLatentCommandCursor to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, motordriver

I use Motor driver of mongoDB in my django project and I have problem to convert my data(who comes from database as cursor) to list, here is my code:

```
documents = db.factor.aggregate([{"$limit": 3},
     {"$lookup": {"from": "subfactor", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "factor_id", "as": "subfactor"}}])

for d in await list(documents):
    print(d)
```

and the Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 595, in run_until_complete
self.run_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 563, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1808, in _run_once
event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 468, in select
fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
```

Comment: I have no idea regarding the mongoDB/Django part, but the errors talk about `timeout`s: could that be the problem, maybe the operation is too slow?

Comment: @Pietro tnx for your comment,  this is not problem, the problem is converting the data who came from mongo to Python code.

Comment: What's your error exactly? You stripped first line of error. Also is cursor iterable? I guess it shouldn't be as library is async based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Motor but a quick check in their [docs](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document) shows this:

Cursor is async iterable, so you can use async for to iterate:

```py
async for document in db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 2}}):
    pprint.pprint(document)
```

You can turn this into a list with a async list comprehention:

```py
items = [x async for x in db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 2}})]
```

Also they have helper functions to convert a cursor to an awaitable list:

```py
items = await db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 2}}).to_list(length=100)
```